# SQL how to count census points occurring between date records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I’m using MS-SQL-2008 R2 trying to write a script that calculates the Number of Hospital Beds occupied on any given day, at 2 census points: midnight, and 09:00.

I’m working from a data set of patient Ward Stays. Basically, each row in the table is a record of an individual patient's stay on a single ward, and records the date/time the patient is admitted onto the ward, and the date/time the patient leaves the ward.

A sample of this table is below:

```
Ward_Stay_Primary_Key |   Ward_Start_Date_Time  |   Ward_End_Date_Time
          1           | 2017-09-03 15:04:00.000 | 2017-09-27 16:55:00.000
          2           | 2017-09-04 18:08:00.000 | 2017-09-06 18:00:00.000
          3           | 2017-09-04 13:00:00.000 | 2017-09-04 22:00:00.000
          4           | 2017-09-04 20:54:00.000 | 2017-09-08 14:30:00.000
          5           | 2017-09-04 20:52:00.000 | 2017-09-13 11:50:00.000
          6           | 2017-09-05 13:32:00.000 | 2017-09-11 14:49:00.000
          7           | 2017-09-05 13:17:00.000 | 2017-09-12 21:00:00.000
          8           | 2017-09-05 23:11:00.000 | 2017-09-06 17:38:00.000
          9           | 2017-09-05 11:35:00.000 | 2017-09-14 16:12:00.000
          10          | 2017-09-05 14:05:00.000 | 2017-09-11 16:30:00.000
```

The key thing to note here is that a patient’s Ward Stay can span any length of time, from a few hours to many days.

The following code enables me to calculate the number of beds at both census points for any given day, by specifying the date in the case statement:

```
SELECT 
     '05/09/2017' [Date]
    ,SUM(case when Ward_Start_Date_Time <= '05/09/2017 00:00:00.000' AND (Ward_End_Date_Time >= '05/09/2017 00:00:00.000' OR Ward_End_Date_Time IS NULL)then 1 else 0 end)[No. Beds Occupied at 00:00]
    ,SUM(case when Ward_Start_Date_Time <= '05/09/2017 09:00:00.000' AND (Ward_End_Date_Time >= '05/09/2017 09:00:00.000' OR Ward_End_Date_Time IS NULL)then 1 else 0 end)[No. Beds Occupied at 09:00]  

FROM 
    WardStaysTable
```

And, based on the sample 10 records above, generates this output:

```
   Date     | No. Beds Occupied at 00:00 | No. Beds Occupied at 09:00
05/09/2017  |             4              |             4
```

To perform this for any number of days is obviously onerous, so what I’m looking to create is a query where I can specify a start/end date parameter (e.g. 1st-5th Sept), and for the query to then evaluate the Ward_Start_Date_Time and Ward_End_Date_Time variables for each record, and – grouping by the dates defined in the date parameter – count each time the 00:00:00.000 and 09:00:00.000 census points fall between these 2 variables, to give an output something along these lines (based on the above 10 records):

```
   Date    | No. Beds Occupied at 00:00 | No. Beds Occupied at 09:00     
01/09/2017 |             0              |            0
02/09/2017 |             0              |            0     
03/09/2017 |             0              |            0
04/09/2017 |             1              |            1
05/09/2017 |             4              |            4
```

I’ve approached this (perhaps naively) thinking that if I use a cte to create a table of dates (defined by the input parameters), along with associated midnight and 9am census date/time points, then I could use these variables to group and evaluate the dataset.

So, this code generates the grouping dates and census date/time points:

```
DECLARE 
  @StartDate DATE = '01/09/2017'
 ,@EndDate DATE = '05/09/2017'
 ,@0900 INT = 540

SELECT  
     DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) [Date]
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate))) [MidnightDate]
    ,DATEADD(mi, @0900,(CONVERT(DATETIME,(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate))))) [0900Date]

FROM    
( 
SELECT  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS nbr
FROM      sys.columns c
) nbrs

WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

The stumbling block I’ve hit is how to join the cte to the WardStays dataset, because there’s no appropriate key… I’ve tried a few iterations of using a subquery to make this work, but either I’m taking the wrong approach or I’m getting my syntax in a mess.

In simple terms, the logic I’m trying to create to get the output is something like:

```
SELECT
[Date]
,SUM (case when  WST.Ward_Start_Date_Time <= [MidnightDate] AND (WST.Ward_End_Date_Time >= [MidnightDate] OR WST.Ward_End_Date_Time IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) [No. Beds Occupied at 00:00]
,SUM (case when  WST.Ward_Start_Date_Time <= [0900Date] AND (WST.Ward_End_Date_Time >= [0900Date] OR WST.Ward_End_Date_Time IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) [No. Beds Occupied at 09:00]

FROM WardStaysTable WST

GROUP BY [Date]
```

Is the above somehow possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree and need to take a different approach altogether? Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT CAST(@StartDate as DATETIME) as dte
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, dte)
      FROM dates
      WHERE dte < @EndDate
     )
SELECT dates.dte [Date],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Ward_Start_Date_Time <= dte AND
                     Ward_END_Date_Time >= dte
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as num_beds_0000,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Ward_Start_Date_Time <= dte + CAST('09:00' as DATETIME) AND
                     Ward_END_Date_Time >= dte + CAST('09:00' as DATETIME)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as num_beds_0900
FROM dates LEFT JOIN
     WardStaysTable wt
     ON wt.Ward_Start_Date_Time <= DATEADD(day, 1, dates.dte) AND
        wt.Ward_END_Date_Time >= dates.dte
GROUP BY dates.dte
ORDER BY dates.dte;
```

The cte is just creating the list of dates.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff - many thanks, this works a treat. I've not seen an example before of using a function within the join, so I can see this opening up all sorts of possibilities for me going forward! Thanks again for your help. R, Jon

Answer (score 0):

What a cool exercise.  Here is what I came up with:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID int, StartDte datetime, EndDte datetime)
INSERT INTO #tmp values(1,'2017-09-03 15:04:00.000','2017-09-27 06:55:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(2,'2017-09-04 08:08:00.000','2017-09-06 18:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(3,'2017-09-04 13:00:00.000','2017-09-04 22:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(4,'2017-09-04 20:54:00.000','2017-09-08 14:30:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(5,'2017-09-04 20:52:00.000','2017-09-13 11:50:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(6,'2017-09-05 13:32:00.000','2017-09-11 14:49:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(7,'2017-09-05 13:17:00.000','2017-09-12 21:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(8,'2017-09-05 23:11:00.000','2017-09-06 07:38:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(9,'2017-09-05 11:35:00.000','2017-09-14 16:12:00.000')
INSERT INTO #tmp values(10,'2017-09-05 14:05:00.000','2017-09-11 16:30:00.000')


DECLARE 
  @StartDate DATE = '09/01/2017'
 ,@EndDate DATE = '10/01/2017'
 , @nHours INT = 9

 ;WITH d(OrderDate) AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @StartDate) 
  FROM (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects) AS x(n)
)
, CTE AS(
select OrderDate, t2.*
 from #tmp t2
 cross apply(select orderdate from d ) d
 where StartDte >= @StartDate and EndDte <= @EndDate)

 select OrderDate,
 SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= StartDte and OrderDate <= EndDte THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  [No. Beds Occupied at 00:00],
 SUM(CASE WHEN StartDTE <= DateAdd(hour,@nHours,CAST(OrderDate as datetime)) and DateAdd(hour,@nHours,CAST(OrderDate as datetime))  <= EndDte THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [No. Beds Occupied at 09:00]
   from CTE
  GROUP BY OrderDate
```

This should allow you to check for any hour of the day using the @nHours parameter if you so choose.  If you only want to see records that actually fall within your date range then you can filter the cross apply on start and end dates.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I've given this a go and the format of the output looks good, but haven't quite managed to get the counts to reconcile

Comment: Well I did modify your table rows a little bit so I could test different check in/out times.